# jQuery UI weird redundant CSS selectors?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-selectors

Why does jQueryUI define extra selectors in their CSS?

```
.ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight
```

- The first selector is "Find any element having class `ui-state-highlight`"
- The second means "Find any element having class `ui-state-highlight` and is child of `ui-widget-content`"
- The third is similar to the second.

The last two seem redundant to me, why are there these extra CSS selectors? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the concept of [*CSS selector specificity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The two extra selectors with parent class specifications have a *higher priority* in those contexts, even if a later CSS selector tries to specify a different value for the same properties.

This is especially important in a framework like jQueryUI which is aimed at reuse and flexibility.

For the example you posted, anyone could give `.ui-state-highlight` a different border colour:

```
.ui-state-highlight { border-color: red }
```

But this won’t actually affect any elements with that class *and* a parent container with the `ui-widget-content` or `ui-widget-header` classes, because the more specific CSS sselectors apply to those instead.

Or you can use a different colour to highlight elements in a widget header:

```
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight { border-color: green }
```

jQueryUI uses a small number of well-defined consistent classes like these together with selectively to make it easy to understand the different concepts (like highlighting) while at the same time making it possible to use different effects in different contexts (highlighting in a header or the widget content are separate things).

Comment: Exact ! I'm really tired... ^^